# Изменение прозрачности отдельного участка блока

Tags: css3, jquery, javascript, css

Здравствуйте.
Подскажите, как реализовать нечто подобное. См. картинку. При наведении на красный блок, вертикальная полоса под ним меняет прозрачность. Проблема в том, что полупрозрачный фон занимает 100% ширины окна.
[image]
Благодарю за советы.

Answer (score 1):

В css можно прописывать `background` для блока в формате `RGBA`, то есть учитывать не только цвет `background`, но и его прозрачность. И эта прозрачность не будет влиять на содержимое в отличии от параметра `opacity`.

В css у вас получаются вот такие стили:

```
.container-item {
  background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.4); /* 255, 255, 255 это белый цвет в RGB, 0.4 полупрозрачность 40%, методом тыка можно подобрать нужную */
  transition: background 0.3s linear; /* Для более плавного изменения прозрачности можно добавить transition */
}

.container-item:hover {
  background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0); /* Background пропадает */
}
```

Comment: Это все понятно. Это азбука.
Вопрос в том, что полупрозрачным является весь большой блок (на всю фоновую картинку), т.е. нужно либо менять прозрачность его части (полоса), либо делать отдельный полупрозрачный фон для блока с красными плашками(фикс ширины) и для широкой полупрозрачной подложки (ширина которой 100%), но как? Это же не Photoshop, здесь масок нет.

Comment: Фоновая картинка отдельно (внешний контейнер), блоки с плашками отдельно поверх фоновой картинки по высоте внешнего блока. А вариант изменения background при наведении именно на плашку, а не на весь блок с плашкой вам написал @Deonis

Comment: Наверное, у меня не получается внятно объяснить. 
Картинка с домами не имеет отношения к сути. Я о ней вообще не говорю.
Есть полупрозрачный оверлей-блок А, который занимает всю ширину окна браузера. Есть блок фиксированной ширины- блок Б, который размещен по центру и который содержит 4 блока с красными плашками - блока В.
При наведении на блок В я меняю его прозрачность на 100% - это понятно, но он же вместе со своим родителем, блоком Б, находится внутри большого (100% ширины окна) блока А, который тоже непрозрачен.
Т.е. непрозрачно все пространство ширины окна, а не только блоки с фикс шир.

Comment: Я вас понял, вам нужно сделать 3 колонки, где центральная колонка это блок с красными плашками, а левая и правая это такие же как плашки полупрозрачные уши, как вариант попробуйте вариант №7 для ваших ушей: http://htmlbook.ru/samlayout/tipovye-makety/rezinovyi-trekhkolonochnyi-maket

Comment: Да, спасибо, попробую.

Comment: Все получилось, то, что нужно. Благодарю за помощь.

Answer (score 1):

[[@rebroff](/users/25262/rebroff)](/users/25262/rebroff), если нужно проявлять полосу при наведении именно на розовый блок, то тут нужно подключать JS. А если достаточно наведения на саму полоску, то [можно сделать таким образом](http://jsfiddle.net/bree6dr3/3/):

```
#wrapper {
    display: flex;
    height: 100vh;
}
#wrapper > div {
    flex: 1 0 auto;
    text-align: center;
    border: 1px solid #999;
    background: rgba(255, 255, 255, .5);
}
#wrapper > div:hover {
    background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0);
}
#wrapper > div:before {
    display: inline-block;
    height: 100%;
    content:'';
    vertical-align: middle;
}
.red { /* ваши розовые блоки */
    display: inline-block;
    width: 90%;
    height: 200px;
    background: #de4f4f;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Comment: Дело в том, что есть блок с плашками, а справа и слева от него - полупрозрачный фон. Т.е. залиты полупрозрачностью не только блоки-полоски, содержащие плашки, но и вся ширина окна браузера справа и слева.

Comment: @rebroff, ну и пусть себе плашки с красными блоками будут посередине, а остальную часть оставьте как есть. Например, [вот так][1] мы получаем две плашки с красными блоками и реагирующими на :hover, а пространство по краям - курит в сторонке. Или я не могу понять в чем вы видите сложность.

   [1]:http://jsfiddle.net/bree6dr3/4/

Comment: @Deonis, я так понял плашки фиксированной ширины будут, ибо картинка

Comment: @MasterAlex, нет, вы не правильно поняли. Они будут резиновыми и по высоте, и по ширине. Могли ж и сами проверить )

Comment: @Deonis, думаю, что это вы неправильно поняли мои слова, у вас всё резиновое, дальше некуда, а вот у автора по ширине должны быть фиксированнные.

Comment: @MasterAlex, я чего-то подумал, что вы спрашивали ))

Comment: Все правильно, полоски с красными фиговинами - фикс ширины, равно как и блок их содержащий, а вот полупрозрачные "уши" справа и слева - тянутся.

Comment: @rebroff, дык в чем проблема. [Смотрите][1]. Плашки с красными блоками фиксированы, а остальная часть резиновая. 

   [1]:http://jsfiddle.net/bree6dr3/6/